# React.js load Image not working from Public Folder

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am currently learning React.js and i want to load Images from the Public Folder. But for some Reasons, this is not working.
My configuration looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fYXq.png)

The Component where i want to display the Image looks like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Tile from "../../../Tiles/Tile/Tile";
import './../../../Tiles/Tiles.sass';

function Market() {

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Market</h1>
            <div className="Tiles__Container">
                <Tile src="Images/img-1.jpg"/>
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Market;
```

The Component which i am calling:

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Tile(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Tiles__Item">
            <Link className="Tiles__Item__Link" to={props.path}>
                <figure className="Tiles__Item__Pic-Wrap" data-category={props.label}>
                    <img className="Tiles__Item__Img" src="Images/img-1.jpg" alt={props.label}/>
                </figure>
                <div className="Tiles__Item__Info">
                    <h5 className="Tiles__Item__Text">{props.text}</h5>
                    <h6 className="Tiles__Item__Text">{props.perAmount}</h6>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tile;
```

When i look at the changes it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NFI1.png)

If i look at the Developer console, the Image gets loaded from here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anBFg.png)

Which is wrong, the Location should look like this:
http://localhost:3001/Images/img-1.jpg

Yours
Simagdo

Comment: try `<Tile src="/Images/img-1.jpg"/>` to make path relative to the root url

Comment: I tried your Idea, but it is still loading from the same Location:
http://localhost:3000/shops/Images/img-1.jpg

Comment: Oh, you how to update img src as well, with same logic. Not sure why you are sending src prop in Tile.

Comment: I followed a Tutorial where he does exactly the Same. In another App i build following the Tutorial i use the same Component and there it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Import the image and use it that way

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Tile from "../../../Tiles/Tile/Tile";
import './../../../Tiles/Tiles.sass';
import img1 from '../../../../../public/Images/img-1.jpg'; // Here we are importing the image directly

function Market() {

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Market</h1>
            <div className="Tiles__Container">
                <Tile src={img1}/>
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Market;
```

In the component we passed in img1 as the src prop so let's use it

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Tile(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Tiles__Item">
            <Link className="Tiles__Item__Link" to={props.path}>
                <figure className="Tiles__Item__Pic-Wrap" data-category={props.label}>
                    <img className="Tiles__Item__Img" src={props.src} alt={props.label}/>
                </figure>
                <div className="Tiles__Item__Info">
                    <h5 className="Tiles__Item__Text">{props.text}</h5>
                    <h6 className="Tiles__Item__Text">{props.perAmount}</h6>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tile;
```